# how to pause progressbar in c#

Tags: c#, timer, progress-bar

I have a progressbar which completes in 20 minutes. I used timer control to increment in progressbar. Now I want after every 5 minutes it pause for 2 minutes no increase in progress in these minutes and after 2 minutes it resumes again. How to do it? Here is my code

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    circularProgressBar1.Increment(1);
    circularProgressBar1.Text = circularProgressBar1.Value.ToString();
    circularProgressBar1.SuperscriptText = "%";
}
```

This is working fine but how to pause it automatically after every 5 minutes.

Comment: What is the `Interval` value?

Comment: 1200000 is my interval value

Comment: Do you want it to go faster when it is running so that it still completes in 20 minutes? Or should it take longer then?

Comment: An `Interval` of 1200000 means 20 minutes. Judging from your code I would have guessed that you have an `Interval` of 0.2 minutes = 12000... Does your progress bar not start at 0?

Comment: progress bar is staring from 0. it is completing in 20 minutes now. But obviously when I pause for 2 minutes it will take longer time to complete. But it does not matter. I just want to pause it for 2 minutes after every 5 minutes

Comment: use `Timespan`, name it say `passedTime`. add amount of timer interval to `passedTime` at every timer tick. when this timespan reaches 5 minutes, pause the timer. change the interval to 2 minutes. start the timer. set a flag name it say `progressPaused` to true. after timer tick if this flag was true means we passed 2 min pause. set this flag to false. pause the timer. change interval back to previous interval. start timer.

Comment: note, if you cant access timer in timer_tick method directly, you can cast `sender` to `Timer` which is your actual timer, then use that.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary can you please tell me code please.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary please elaborate it in code so I can better understand it how to do it

Comment: ok, ill try when I reach home, maybe 6 hours later. sorry for late response.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136438/discussion-between-ramisha-farrukh-and-m-kazem-akhgary).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you remember the start time and use it to calculate the elapsed time in each Tick. Then you can check if you are outside a break interval, i.e. if you are before the first break (`elapsed.Minutes < activeMinutes`) or if you are after the first break (`elapsed.Minutes >= activeMinutes + pauseMinutes`) *and* not in another break interval (`elapsed.Minutes % (activeMinutes + pauseMinutes) < activeMinutes)`).

The complete code would look something like this:

```
private DateTime _startTime;
private int activeMinutes = 5;
private int pauseMinutes = 2;
private Timer _timer;

private void StartTimer()
{
    if(_timer != null)
    {
        // detach event handler from old timer before creating a new one
        _timer.Tick -= timer1_Tick;
    }
    _timer = new Timer();
    _timer.Interval = 12000;
    _timer.Tick += timer1_Tick;
    _timer.Start();
    _startTime = DateTime.Now;
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    TimeSpan elapsed = DateTime.Now.Subtract( _startTime );
    if( elapsed.Minutes < activeMinutes ||
       (elapsed.Minutes >= activeMinutes + pauseMinutes &&
        elapsed.Minutes % (activeMinutes + pauseMinutes) < activeMinutes))
    {
        circularProgressBar1.Increment(1);
        circularProgressBar1.Text = circularProgressBar1.Value.ToString();
        circularProgressBar1.SuperscriptText = "%";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use TimeSpan and add interval to this TimeSpan at every timer tick. modify the timer when you reach 5 minutes and start over. here is example, its not tested so some debug maybe required.

I suggest set initial interval of timer to 1000 milliseconds so progress bar updates every second, although you can set longer intervals too.

```
private double interval = 1000; // one second interval so progress bar updates every second.
private TimeSpan elapsed; // time span that reaches 5 minutes. this will reset to 0 after 5 minutes.
private TimeSpan totalElapsed; // total time passed. used to set value of progress bar
private bool progressPaused; // flag, true if progressbar is at 2 min pause, otherwise false

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    const int fiveMinutes = 5*1000*60;
    const int twoMinutes = 2*1000*60;
    const int totalMinutes = 20*1000*60;

    var timer = (Timer) sender; // assuming Timer is System.Timers.Timer

    if(timer.Enabled == false) return;

    if (progressPaused) 
    {
        // progressbar was paused. prepare to start again

        timer.Enabled = false;
        timer.AutoReset = true;
        timer.Interval = interval; // previous interval
        progressPaused = false;
        timer.Enabled = true;
        return;
    }

    // add interval of timer to TimeSpans
    totalElapsed = totalElapsed.Add(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timer.Interval));
    elapsed = elapsed.Add(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timer.Interval));

    if (elapsed.Milliseconds > fiveMinutes) // if we reached 5 minutes
    {
        elapsed = default(TimeSpan); // reset timespan from 5 min to 0
        timer.Enabled = false;
        timer.AutoReset = false; // auto reset should be off because we only pause once per 2 minutes. (although this may have no effect)
        interval = timer.Interval;
        timer.Interval = twoMinutes; // two minute pause
        progressPaused = true; // set falg
        timer.Enabled = true;
    }

    circularProgressBar1.Value = (int)(totalElapsed.Milliseconds/(double)totalMinutes*100); // calculate new progressbar value. (elapsed/total*100)
    circularProgressBar1.Text = circularProgressBar1.Value.ToString();
    circularProgressBar1.SuperscriptText = "%";
}
```

Comment: this code is not working. progressbar is stuck on 0% and not increasing

Comment: Remove this line and test again. timer.AutoReset=false

Answer (score -1):

calculate the difference between to date startdate (get it before the progress start  ) and the enddate (get it every time you get into timer1_Tick)

```
DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;


private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
DateTime endTime = DateTime.Now

TimeSpan span = endTime.Subtract( startTime );
if(span.Minutes % 5 == 0){
        circularProgressBar1.Increment(1);
        circularProgressBar1.Text =    circularProgressBar1.Value.ToString();
        circularProgressBar1.SuperscriptText = "%";
 }
}
```

Comment: This will run for a minute and then pause for four minutes.

Answer (score -1):

Timer timer;

```
    int countTime;
    bool breakReached;
    int breakTime;
    int breakLength;
    int countToFinish;
    int finishTime;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.Interval = 1000;

        breakTime = 300; // in sek
        breakLength = 120; // in sek
        finishtime = 1200;
        breakReached = false;
        timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
        timer.Start();
    }

    private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (countTime != breakTime && breakReached != true)
        {
            progressBar1.Increment(1);
            progressBar1.Text = progressBar1.Value.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            //break was reached
            breakReached = true;
            countTime = 0;
            while(countTime != breakLength)
            {
                //do the 2 min break
            }
            breakReached = false;
        }
        countTime++;
        countToFinish ++;
        if(countToFinish == finishTime)
        {//its done}
    }
```

Comment: To have 20 minutes of 'active time', you should set your interval to 12000. Otherwise you reach 100% after 100s of 'active time'  which makes the progressbar complete in 1m40s without even one break :-)

Comment: Once `countTime` equals `breakTime` you go into the `else` branch and get stuck in the `while` loop. Then you never leave it as all future calls go to the `else` branch as well (because `breakReached` is true then) and nobody is ever going to increase `countTime` or set `breakReached` to false. So from the beginning of the first break, you accumulate event handlers in infinite loops.